# Spring Security 2 Custom Authentication Provider not saving security context

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

I've changed the default Authentication Provider for a Custom one.

This is my AuthenticationProvider

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Autowired
private ParamsProperties paramsProperties;  

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    //Check username and passwd
    String user = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
    String pass = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
    if(StringUtils.isBlank(user) || StringUtils.isBlank(pass) ){
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Incorrect username/password");
    }

    //Create SSO
    SingleSignOnService service = new SingleSignOnService(paramsProperties.getServicesServer());
    try {
        //Check logged
        service.setUsername(authentication.getName());
        service.setPassword(authentication.getCredentials().toString());
        ClientResponse response = service.call();
        String result = response.getEntity(String.class);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue(result, new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>() {} );
        //Read code
        String code = (String)map.get("code");
        log.debug(" ** [Authenticate] Result: " + code );
        for (String s : (List<String>)map.get( "messages" ) ) {
            log.debug(" [Authenticate] Message: " + s );
        }

        if ( code.equals( "SESSION_CREATED" ) || code.equals( "SESSION_UPDATED" ) || code.equals( "SESSION_VERIFIED" ) ) {              
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken tokenSSO = LoginHelper.getuserSringTokenFromAuthService(map);            
            return tokenSSO;                
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException( e.getMessage() );
    }
}


public boolean supports(Class authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

And this is my security.xml

```
<http>
  <form-login default-target-url ="/Login.html" always-use-default-target="true" login-page="/Login.html" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/Login.html" />  
  <http-basic />
  <logout logout-success-url="/Login.html" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="localeFilter" class="com.mycomp.comunes.server.spring.controller.login.MyLocaleFilter" lazy-init="true">
    <custom-filter position="LAST"/>
</beans:bean>  

<beans:bean id="authenticationProvider" class="com.indra.rfef.comunes.server.spring.manager.autenticacion.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
  <custom-authentication-provider />
</beans:bean>
```

It gets over my CustomAuthenticationProvider, and authenticates correctly the user. But when returning `tokenSSO`, of type `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, it seems it's not saving the user on the Security Context, and when I redirect the user (on the callback of the `authenticate`) to the index.html, I get redirected back to Login.html.

Why could this happen? I'm I forgetting something?

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Please fix your configuration:

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/Login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>        
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <form-login login-page="/Login.html" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" authentication-failure-url="/Login.html" />  
    <http-basic />
    <logout logout-success-url="/Login.html" />
</http>
```

1. Remove `default-target-url ="/Login.html"`. It makes the redirection after login to the same login page. The default is `/`.
2. Add security on all URLs `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>`
3. Do not remove the anonymous access from the login page
4. Why you need BasicAuthentication? Remove it if not required: `<http-basic />`

Comment: Thanks, but by the way it wasn't really a CustomAuthenticationProvider issue. I was handling an issue in my SpringGwtCoreServlet as user was not in SpringSecurityContext. I had to add this and worked!  

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(tokenSSO);  
SecurityContext auth = new SecurityContextImpl();
auth.setAuthentication(tokenSSO);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(auth);`